# Java Client .class File Protection

Tags: java, security

I am in the requirements phase of building a Java EE application that will most likely run on a GlassFish/JBoss backend (doesn't matter for now).  I *know* I shouldn't be thinking about architecture at requirements time, but one can't help but start to imagine how the components would all snap together :-)

Here are some hard, non-flexible requirements on the client-side:
(1) The client application will be a Swing box
(2) The client is free to download, but will use a subscription model (*thus requiring a login mechanism with server-side authentication/authorization, etc.*)
**(3) Yes, Java is the *best* platform solution for the problem at hand for reasons outside the scope of this post**
(4) The client-side .class files need safeguarding against decompiling

That last (4th) requirement is the basis of this post.

I'm not really worried about someone actually decompiling and getting at my source code: in the end, it's just Swing controls driven by some lightweight business logic.

I'm worried about a scenario where someone decompiles my code, modifies it to exploit/attack the server, re-compiles, and fires it up.

I've envisioned all sorts of nasty solutions, but didn't know if this was a common problem with a common solution for Java EE developers. Any thoughts?

**Not interested in "code obfuscation" techniques!**

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I don't actually understand... If authentication and authorization happens on the server side than what could malicious client do?

Comment: Don't forget that in a network environment that "the bad guy" can put a sniffer on his end and figure out what is being sent as well.

Comment: @Suirtmed: The same is with any web browser client application. The solution is simple - use encrypted communication (SSL). Basically, I can't find any reason to justify code encryption.

Comment: I can easily use a web proxy to look at the unencrypted data on a SSL pipe.  Calls that are authorized to untrusted users must presume that they will be attacked and hardened appropriately, SSL is only part of the answer and only solves man-in-the-middle attacks where digital signing is not being used.

Comment: @Zac, what search terms have you used on stackoverflow so far?

Comment: Seems you just need to make sure your server application is rock-solid. Trust no communication whatsoever, not even from a logged in and apparently legit client. If your server software is built properly, it shouldn't matter if the users can decompile and strip the client application down to its bones. If there's something in the client application that indicates a possible security leak though, then there's something wrong with the server software.

Comment: @Rekin I'm 2 weeks late here, but anyway: SSL will only help to protect communication from client to server against an attacker. It won't help if the client itself is the attacker.

Comment: @sfussenegger: Of course. I assume the server is bullet proof anyway. This is how it should be. Back-end should do all the necessary checks and validations. Client application *can* have this too, but mostly for improved user experience. No one ever should be granting client application all rights. Policy check belongs to back-end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm here to bring you the bad news. You cannot stop this.

I dug into this deeply one time. At the lowest levels in the JVM the Classloader must get an unencrypted byte stream that is the class file. You cannot change that short of replacing the JVM with your own code. Furthermore, there is a hook there that allows the byte stream to be viewed (copied, etc.). No matter what you do at higher levels, the JVM will always get to this point and allow access to your class file. Once the class file is obtained it can be decompiled. Obfuscation techniques and tools can slow that down or make it difficult, but they also cannot stop it.

I would strongly suggest that you protect your server using tried and true security methods. Don't embed the secret sauce in something you give to the client. They will get at it somehow if they are determined enough.

Comment: +1. Exactly. You probably heard of breaking the Skype communication algorithm. Security by obscurity is NO security.

Comment: it's a good post and true. Always build your servers secure and robust being able to deal w/ any content coming from the wire.

Answer (score 9):

You must assume that the code WILL be decompiled and WILL be used to exploit/attack the server.

Only trust what the server is doing.

Comment: Just to add: @Zac: Your concern should be in **how** you authenticate your users on the server, as theoretically an attacker doesn't need your application in order to cause harm.

Answer (score 3):

I see this as a common "strong v. weak" cryptography problem: If knowledge of the algorithm is sufficient to compromise the message (i.e. your login), the cryptography is weak.

What about using something like OAuth instead?  Through a one-time authentication process with the server, the client application is given tokens, and the server can always revoke authorization for any given client if it's ever necessary.

Also note that authentication is no substitute for authorization.  Just because your system thinks it knows who someone is does not mean they should be authorized to do anything they want.  You'll need to also deploy good access control such as are provided by JAAS or Spring Security, and link that to the authentication.  The first check on any call from the client is for authentication, the second is whether that particular client is authorized to make the call in the first place.

Regardless of what you do, your server needs to only allow calls based on the authorization granted to a user.

Answer (score 1):

Use a decent server authentication, do not store usernames, passwords or encryption keys in the application, and then as Rekin comments, I do not see what in your code can betray your server protection.

If you absolutley need to encrypt communications (doesn't look like a requirement) use SSL or any public key cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

I have a "thinking out of the box" solution for point number 4.

I am assuming your application has network access as it goes online to authenticate...

1. You have a bunch or "jar" files with classes in them. The only difference is that the classes are encrypted using a symmetric key.
2. When the application starts, the application goes online get authenticated and fetches the key over a secure connection (eg SSL).
3. You then load all the encrypted files into memory and decrypt them.
4. You then create a custom class loader and load the decrypted class into the class loader using ClassLoader.defineClass
5. You are then good to go!

This is not a not a concrete method of doing things and as i said its out the box. But it does make it slightly harder to steal your code. But as the other posters have said, you cannot hide secrets in your code that is on the client side.

Comment: Please see my answer above. I've investigated exactly this. Unfortunately it doesn't protect you. Your custom classloader must pass control at some point to a concrete classloader that is provided with the JVM. The hook is always there, after decryption.

Comment: @rfeak - 100% agree with you.